# Should I use 2 models to store similar data but with different uses in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, models

Hi there I'm currently in the process of planning a very basic rails app. I want to create small weight tracking app this will store a weight(number) within a Weight model there will also be the ability to add a goal-weight(number) every week a user would enter their new weight and it will be compared against the goal weight and show completion % etc to the user.

Now my question is would I have both a Weight model and a Goal model or should it be a single Weight model with some extra meta information to set a weight as a goal? I will admit im very much a noob with rails my gut says 2 models but I could be completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty subjective answer, but I would separate them for two reasons.

1. More modular. For example, you might want some model validations on Weight model, but not Goal model. In this case, it's easier to make them into two different models rather than have them in one.
2. Model associations. You may want to create model associations in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Weight wouldn't even be a model for me, weight would be a parameter from user, as so would goal_weight. You could implement a method `weight_over_goal_weight?` afterwards to check if weight is over or equal goal_weight.

Comment: I think "weight tracking" implies that there will many `weights` and `goals` created over time. So having them as just attributes won't satisfy this requirement well.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the whole concept of the app. Actually, re-reading it I may find that User would actually have many weights. That is probably my bad there, yes. If that was the case I would probably split them in two as well.

Comment: And I personally prefer to have at least 2 tables for `Users`: **1.** login/auth stuff (username, password, email, last-login-timestamp, etc.). **2.** personal data which isn't important for table relations (real name, birthday, instant messenger, etc.). Then maybe a third table for permissions if they are mapped using a many-to-many relationship. But if these are simple roles they'd go in table **1** with the login credentials. ... In case of the question author, I'd choose a separate table for the weight entries (especially if this is a many-to-one relationship).